# How to send delivery confirmation from the swipe up & killed IOS chat app

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, voip

I am using react-native to build a chat application for Android/IOS. I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send push notification in Android/IOS.

Now suppose a case when A user (Android/IOS) send a text message to B user (IOS) and the receiver IOS device is swiped up & killed from the memory. My high priority FCM push notification is not waking the IOS device in the background so that it can send a confirmation message to the sender. Although I can send a normal display notification to IOS regarding the message, that will not send any feedback to the sender.

I have tried APNS but even that didn't awake the swiped up and killed the app. Lastly, I tried VOIP. VOIP works great but the APP store review process rejected the app with the reason that VOIP is not for this purpose

Please guide

Comment: If the user kills the app then it can't do anything; iOS assumes that the user wanted it dead.

Comment: But other social media apps like whatsapp can still send the message and receive confirmation from the receiver if you swiped up & kill the app

Comment: I have tested that VOIP feature can awake the app, do you think whatsapp is using the VOIP feature for this?

Comment: Yes, because whatsapp is a voip app.  Voip apps are treated differently because the user might miss a call if the app is terminated.

Comment: Although whatsapp is a VOIP app but using VOIP for sending message and receving confirmation for normal text mesaage is not acceptable by Apple

Comment: Right. If you are a voip app you can use pushkit. If you aren’t, you can’t

Comment: This is kind of bad just because I need VOIP for normal text message push, I have to use calling in the app just to trick apple that I am using VOIP for calling but truth is that the main purpose of using it just to awake the app. Wow

Comment: Android is best, there is 1 type of push with different priority levels irrespective of your use case -VOIP/non-VOIP

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend trying to “trick” Apple, but you can try.They can pull your app. Simpler to accept that if the person kills your app then you won’t get delivery notifications.

Comment: But if other social media chat applications like Whatsapp, Line, hike, fb messenger provide this feature of always receiving notifications (because they have VOIP, maybe for calling) then my chat app must also provide the same. This means I have to use VOIP in the app